# R convert large character string to dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am having trouble converting a large text string to a dataframe. I've been unable to figure this simple task out yet. Hoping for your help.

```
x <- "1 apple 200 blueberry 3000 pear 4400 raspberry"
```

I'd like to convert this to a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id    name
1     apple
200   blueberry
30000 pear
4400  raspberrry
```

Comment: OK, you've to a reproducible example but your attempt at the code is missing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can use `gsub` with `read.table`

```
read.table(text=gsub("(?<=[a-z])\\s+", "\n", x, perl=TRUE), 
            header=FALSE, col.names = c("id", "name"))
#    id      name
#1    1     apple
#2  200 blueberry
#3 3000      pear
#4 4400 raspberry
```

Or with `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(gsub("(?<=[a-z])\\s+", "\n", x, perl=TRUE), col.names = c("id", "name"))
```

---

Or this would also work without the `gsub` by specifying the `col.names` with `read.table`

```
read.table(text=x,col.names=c('ID','Name'))
#    ID      Name
#1    1     apple
#2  200 blueberry
#3 3000      pear
#4 4400 raspberry
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
r <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
data.frame(id=as.numeric(r[c(TRUE,FALSE)]), name=r[c(FALSE,TRUE)])

#    id      name
#1    1     apple
#2  200 blueberry
#3 3000      pear
#4 4400 raspberry
```

Comment: This will work with the example string given but Tom O should be aware if the string doesn't match that format exactly this will fail.

Comment: @989 Could you explain what exactly r[c(TRUE,FALSE)] does? Obviously, it gets just the numbers but why?

Comment: @JonGrub `r[c(TRUE,FALSE)]` and `r[c(FALSE,TRUE)]` take the odd and even indices of the vector, respectively. Its related to vector recycling.

Answer (score 6):

```
  read.table(text=x,col.names=c('ID','Name'))
  #     ID      Name
    1    1     apple
    2  200 blueberry
    3 3000      pear
    4 4400 raspberry
```